# Como passo o valor para o: "this.props" - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

eu comecei a estudar React Native na versão 0.55.4, e parece que mudou umas coisas na versão mais atual (0.59.8), agora estou com dificuldade de passar/atribui valores no `this.props.modificaNome`, segue um exemplo abaixo de como eu faço em um `TextInput` e o erro que apresenta:

Dependências utilizadas:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.7.3",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

Eu não sei se essa mudança foi no React Native ou Redux. Mas tá apresentando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do meu código:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
 View,
 StyleSheet,
 StatusBar,
 Text,
 TouchableHighlight,
 TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import {
 modificaNome
} from '../reducers/AutenticacaoReducers';


class Confirmar extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {};
 }

 render() {
   return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#FFF' }}>
     <StatusBar backgroundColor="#104E8B" barStyle="light-content" />
     <View>

      <TextInput
       placeholder=" Digite o seu nome... "
       style={{ fontSize: 15, height: 50 }}
       selectionColor="#696969"
       underlineColorAndroid="#FFFFFF"
       returnKeyType="go"
       multiline={false}
       numberOfLines={1}
       spellCheck={false}
       maxLength={15}
       autoCorrect={false}
       value={this.props.nome}
       onChangeText={texto => this.props.modificaNome(texto)}
      />

      <TouchableHighlight
       style={Estilos.buttom}
       underlayColor='#CDC9C9'
       accessibilityLabel="Clique aqui para ler o meu convite."
       onPress={() => {}}>
       <Text style={{ color: '#FFF', fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>OK</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

     </View>
    </View>
   )
 }
}


const Estilos = StyleSheet.create({
 buttom: {
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  borderColor: '#3A5FCD',
  backgroundColor: '#04B45F',
  borderWidth: 0.5,
  borderRadius: 100,
  width: 280,
  height: 40
 },
})

const mapStateProps = state => ({
 nome: state.AutenticacaoReducers.nome,
});

export default connect(mapStateProps, {
 modificaNome,
})(Confirmar);
```

O Meu AutenticacaoReducers:

```js
import {
    MODIFICA_NOME,
} from './../actions/Types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    nome: '',
}

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case MODIFICA_NOME:
            return { ...state, nome: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

O Meu AutenticacaoActions:

```js
import {
  MODIFICA_NOME,
} from './Types';

export const modificaNome = (texto) => {
  return {
    type: MODIFICA_NOME,
    payload: texto
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pelo código dá pra entender que vc está importanto a função `modificaNome` e não a recebendo por props, por isso a mensagem

> this.props.modificaNome is not a function

Portanto, seu `onChangeText` deve ficar assim:

```
onChangeText={texto => modificaNome(texto)}
```

Além disso, o `value` de seu `TextInput` deve ser uma variável do estado local:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nome: ''
    };
}
...
<TextInput
    ...
    value={this.state.nome}
    onChangeText={texto => modificaNome(texto)}
/>
```

Por fim, não é interessante disparar uma ação no redux para cada mudança no texto. Uma melhor alternativa seria alterar o estado atual a cada mudança do texto e ter um botão que envie assim que o usuário desejar:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nome: ''
    };
}
...
<TextInput
    ...
    value={this.state.nome}
    onChangeText={texto => this.setState({ nome: texto})}
/>
<Button
   onPress={() => modificaNome(this.state.nome)}
   title="Modificar nome"
/>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda amigo, estou correndo atrás da solução desse problema a dias... Eu realizei essas alterações que você me orientou, mas o erro continua. E não entendo, não é necessário realizar uma alteração no AutenticacaoActions e AutenticacaoReducers?

Comment: O erro agora é: AutenticacaoReducers.modificaNome is not a function

Comment: Essa resposta está incorreta. Você está fazendo do jeito certo, tente atualizar o redux e ve no que dá

Comment: Tente alterar onPress={() => {}} para onPress={() => false} pode nao ser a solucao, mas isso é uma boa prática

Answer (score -1):

a função `connect` recebe dois argumentos que são o `mapStatetoProps` que deve ser uma função e `mapDispatchToProps` que pode ser uma função ou um objeto [ver documentação](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#two-forms-of-mapdispatchtoprops), no seu código você está aparentemente importando os reducers mas o certo seria importa as `actions` ou fazer os `dispatch` delas, no código que você disponibilizou suas actions estão no arquivo `AutenticacaoAction.js` [MapDispatchtoProps](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#providing-a-mapdispatchtoprops-parameter)

> O fornecimento de um `mapDispatchToProps` permite que você especifique quais ações seu componente precisará despachar. Ele permite que você forneça funções para despachar as `actions` como `props`

```js
import {
    modificaNome
} from '../reducers/AutenticacaoReducers';// vc ta importando as action ou reducers?

 . . .

export default connect(mapStateProps, {
    modificaNome,
})(Confirmar);
```

no `mapStatetoProps` você deveria evitar esse encademento que está assim:

```js
const mapStateProps = state => ({
    nome: state.AutenticacaoReducers.nome,
});
```

tente usar algo mais ou menos assim

```js
const mapStateProps = state => ({
    nome: state.nome,
});
```

pra que isso der certo ou seja pra que você consiga fazer o `state.nome` quando você for combinar os `reducers` você deveria fazer algo assim

```js
combineReducers({ nome: AutenticacaoReducers });
```

na [documentação](https://react-redux.js.org/) eles tem um bom tutorial e as boas práticas que são usadas :)

Comment: Não falou nada com nada. O cara tá com o código certinho, o erro pode ser na criação da store. Lucas, edite seu codigo adicionando sua página de rotas/store

Comment: @MuriloMedeiros veja que ele tá importando os reducers 
`import {
 modificaNome
} from '../reducers/AutenticacaoReducers';`, na documentação não fala sobre dar dispatch em reducers https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#providing-a-mapdispatchtoprops-parameter, sim pode tbm haver um erro ao criar a store mas não adianta criar a store direitinho se ele ta dando dispatch nos reducers